# Add/inject React component into pure HTML that came from the back-end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-parsing

I have a pure HTML that came from the back-end. I want to include/inject/add React component into `div` with special `id` in that HTML and render it properly. Guess I should use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`(or html-react-parser) and `ReactDOM.render`, but `ReactDOM.render` doesn't work inside a React component. Is there a way to do that. There is my suggestion, which doesn't seem right at all:

```
export default class MainBoard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {content: { __html: "" }};
    };
    componentWillMount() {
    const dinamicHTML = { __html: "<div class='dinamic-content'><h4 class='content-header'>Dinamic content header</h4><div id='test-component'>This content is dynamically added.</div></div>" };
        this.setState({ content: dinamicHTML});
        ReactDOM.render(<Menu />, document.getElementById('test-component'));
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="main-content-wrapper">
                <h3>MainBoard</h3>
                <div className="dinamic-content-wrapper" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.state.content} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: refer to next,js for rendering react components in server

Comment: I can't really understand how this work for me. Maybe I am not enough familiar with next.js. Can you explain it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is feasible. You use ReactDOM.render to inject a React component inside html element.

But I would reconsider other approaches. Why not return JSON instead of HTML?
Else you get this weird code.

```
const Menu = props => <div>menu</div>;

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main-content-wrapper">
        <h3>MainBoard</h3>
        <div ref={el => (this.dynamicContentWrapper = el)} 
          className="dynamic-content-wrapper" />
      </div>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    const htmlFromAjax = `
      <div class='dynamic-content'>
        <h4 class='content-header'>Dynamic content header</h4>
        <div id='test-component'>This content is dynamically added.</div>
      </div>`;
    this.dynamicContentWrapper.innerHTML = htmlFromAjax;
    ReactDOM.render(<Menu />, this.dynamicContentWrapper.querySelector('#test-component'));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As for trying to render the Menu inside `componentWillMount`, you almost certainly want to restructure your component hierarchy. For example:

```
<Container>
  <Menu />
  <MainBoard />
</Container>
```

You should really only be calling `ReactDOM.render` once.

---

Now to the main question, is there no way of receiving JSON from the server instead? If not, I think you're stuck using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. You would be better off doing this inside `componentDidMount`, rather than `componentWillMount`. E.g:

```
componentDidMount() {
  requestHTML().then(html => this.setState({ content: { __html: html } }))
}
```

With the implementation of `requestHTML` being up to you.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't answer the main question. How to inject React component(Menu for example) in pure HTML that came from the server.

Comment: I see. I think what you want is `renderToString` from `react-dom/server`. Here's an example https://gist.github.com/chrfrasco/41006be4e7b42c09108cd89a336a77ae

Comment: May I am not explaining it right. I don't want just to add some of my components as a string or something. I receive a pure HTML like
`<div id="componentName"> </div>`
I should insert some component in this `div`. The THML can be really big.

Comment: So you receive some html (which may be very large) and want to insert the markup from a react component inside it. Am I understanding correctly? Where do you insert this new HTML after that?

Comment: Yes, you are right. After that I just render it somewhere(in some react component) - it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I've updated the gist that I linked. Let me know if that answers your question and I'll edit my main answer to include it.

Comment: I test it but in the end it render `[object HTMLDivElement]` instead of HTML

Answer (score 0):

Using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is indeed the only way of doing exactly this.

Now as you mention that isn't a particularly great way, depending on the source of this HTML. If there is any way users can insert things in there, you can very quickly have a Cross-Site Scripting situation on your hands.

But if you trust the HTML you can just use what you are doing.